# SwiftUI animations are not working inside List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI the animations inside a `List` are not functioning properly. However, when I replace the `List` with a `ScrollView` and a `LazyVStack`, the animations perform as expected. Is there a solution to fix this? I don't want to switch to `LazyVStack` because I'm using `onMove` and `onDelete` modifiers and some other List-specific stuff.

Environment: Xcode 14.2

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    
    @State var showColor = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            
            if showColor {
                Color.green
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .transition(.scale)
            }

            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    showColor.toggle()
                }
                
            } label: {
                Text("show/hide color")
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way that the frame is updated for a list item, I am not really sure if there is a way to achieve the desired animation.

Two improvements I can think of, however, would be to add a `VStack` around the text and the color like so:

```
struct SomeView: View {

  @State var showColor = false

  var body: some View {
    List {
      VStack {
        if showColor {
          Color.green
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .transition(.scale)
        }
        Button {
          withAnimation {
            showColor.toggle()
          }
        } label: {
          Text("show/hide color")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An alternative improvement, which would make the animation smoother, would be to replace the `if` statement with a "conditional" frame like so.

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @State var showColor = false

  var body: some View {
    List {
      Color.green
        .frame(width: showColor ? 200 : 0, height: showColor ? 200 : 0)
        .transition(.scale)

        Button {
          withAnimation {
            showColor.toggle()
          }

        } label: {
          Text("show/hide color")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

By using a combination of both of those, you should be able to receive the best results for your use case. If the animations are still not good enough, I would consider changing the layout or not using a list.